# range of $a_9$ for sequence $a_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_n$ be sequence which satisfies $a_n\in\mathbb{N}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

If $a_7 = 40$ and for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ :

$$a_{n+2} =
\begin{cases}
    a_{n+1} + a_n & \left(\text{if } a_{n+1} \text{ is not a multiple of } 3\right)\\
    \frac{a_{n+1}}{3} & \left(\text{if } a_{n+1} \text{ is a multiple of } 3\right)
\end{cases}
$$

Find sum of maximum and minimum of $a_9$.

My approach is here :

There is no information about next term, so I tried to find previous term.

If $a_6$ is multiple of $3$, $a_6 = 120, a_7 = 40, a_8 = 160, a_9 = 200.$

If not, $a_7 = a_6 + a_5$. But there is no information about $a_6, a_5$ too.

How can I proceed here?

Comment: If $a_6$ isn't a multiple of $3$, then $a_6=40-a_5$.  If $a_5$ is a multiple of $3$, then, you must have $a_5=30$, $a_6=10$, $a_7=40$, $a_8=50$, and $a_9=90$.  If it's not, then $a_6=a_5+a_4$, and keep going?

Answer (score 0):

Given sequence $a_n$ be 'eventually periodic' if $a_n = 3k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ because :

$$a_n = \cdots,3k,k,4k,5k,9k,3k,\cdots$$

and, four of these numbers ($a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5$) must contain multiple of $3$.

So, $a_7 = 40$ must be inside of period.

Since $40$ is not multiple of $3$, you should check remaining 3 possible cases :

i) $a_7 = 40 = k$

$k=40, a_9=5k=200$

ii) $a_7 = 40 = 4k$

$k=10, a_9 = 9k = 90$

iii) $a_7 = 40 = 5k$

$k=8, a_9 = 3k = 24$

So $a_9 \in \left\{24, 90, 200\right\}$.